# Need the xml of media

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having the 1500 Images in in my media section in the wp-admin.

Can any one know the plugin or another way to export all the images?

i wantto move all that image to my another website so can anyone tell me how can i move that all the images?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'export_args', 'so_25617908' );

function so_25617908( $args ) {
    $args['content'] = 'attachment';
    return $args;
}
```

After that, export all the site data and the XML will contain only attachments:

[image: export screen with All Content selected]